# Manipulating duplicates by merging similar (Is it possiple)

Tags: mysql, duplication

I have row 1 and 2 which they are similar in records except status column.

```
   +-----+------+-------+-----------+----------+---------+
| #id | NAME | STATUS|   c_lan   | Java_lan | Dot_lan |
+-----+------+-------+-----------+----------+---------+
|   1 |  A   |   111 |      yes  |    Q     | W       |
|   1 |  A   |   222 |      yes  |    Q     | W       |
+-----+------+-------+-----------+----------+---------+
```

Now is it possible to have these tow rows (1,2) become as one row as like  below (need to merge status values in to one cell)?

```
+-----+------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+
| #id | NAME | STATUS    |   c_lan   | Java_lan | Dot_lan |
+-----+------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+
|   1 | A    |   111,222 |      yes  |    Q     | W       |
+-----+------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+
```

noting that i am considering this to be done on mysql view

Answer (score 1):

Use [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for this.

Your table:

```
create table foo
(
id int,
name varchar(10),
status int,
c_lan varchar(10),
Java_lan varchar(10),
Dot_lan varchar(10)
);

insert into foo values (  1,'A',111,'yes','Q','W'   );

insert into foo values (  1,'A',222,'yes','Q','W'   );
```

Testcase:

```
mysql> select id, GROUP_CONCAT(status separator ',') as status, c_lan, Java_lan, Dot_lan from foo group by id;
+------+---------+-------+----------+---------+
| id   | status  | c_lan | Java_lan | Dot_lan |
+------+---------+-------+----------+---------+
|    1 | 111,222 | yes   | Q        | W       |
+------+---------+-------+----------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

View:

```
create view concatview as (
select id, GROUP_CONCAT(status separator ',') as status, c_lan, Java_lan, Dot_lan
from foo
group by id
);
```

Test:

```
mysql> select * from concatview;
+------+---------+-------+----------+---------+
| id   | status  | c_lan | Java_lan | Dot_lan |
+------+---------+-------+----------+---------+
|    1 | 111,222 | yes   | Q        | W       |
+------+---------+-------+----------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Obviously you may want to `GROUP` on more than just `id` (depending on what you consider a "duplicate", and may want to order the `GROUP_CONCAT()` in some way, but this points you in the right direction.

Edit to address your comment:

```
mysql> insert into foo values ( 2,'b',555,'yes','Q','W' );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> select id, GROUP_CONCAT(status separator ',') as status, c_lan, Java_lan, Dot_lan
    -> from foo
    -> group by id
    -> ;
+------+---------+-------+----------+---------+
| id   | status  | c_lan | Java_lan | Dot_lan |
+------+---------+-------+----------+---------+
|    1 | 111,222 | yes   | Q        | W       |
|    2 | 555     | yes   | Q        | W       |
+------+---------+-------+----------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: well that caused to return  one row that has in its status coloumn  a group of 111,222 and all other status values unrelated to id 1 ,i have another id's i didnt mentioned in the example 3,4,5,6,7,...

Comment: try to insert into foo values (  2,'b',555,'yes','Q','W'   );
and you will have :just one row returned 1 | 111,222,333 | yes   | Q        | W

Comment: Not true. Question edited.

Comment: Whereas this answer show how to do it, you should think twice about ever doing it.  Searching a commalist is a pain, can't use an index, etc.